# связь volumeClaimTemplates с конкретным pv через storageClassName

Tags: kubernetes

День добрый!
есть непонятность : создаю statefulsets объект по руководству https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

сначало создаю PV.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0004
spec:
  storageClassName: mypv
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  iscsi:
    targetPortal: 10.0.6.102
    iqn: iqn.2014-06.com.vstorage:test2
    lun: 1
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: false
    chapAuthDiscovery: true
    chapAuthSession: true
    secretRef:
      name: t2iscsi-secret

kubectl describe pv/pv0004
Name:            pv0004
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    mypv
Status:          Released
Claim:           default/task-pv-claim
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        5Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:               ISCSI (an ISCSI Disk resource that is attached to     a kubelet's host machine and then exposed to the pod)
    TargetPortal:       10.0.6.102
    IQN:                iqn.2014-06.com.vstorage:test2
    Lun:                1
    ISCSIInterface      default
    FSType:             ext4
    ReadOnly:           false
    Portals:            []
    DiscoveryCHAPAuth:  true
    SessionCHAPAuth:    true
    SecretRef:          &{t2iscsi-secret }
    InitiatorName:      <none>
Events:                 <none>
```

потом сам sfs

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testsfs-srv
  labels:
    app: testsfs
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testsfs
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: testsfs
  labels:
    app: testsfs
spec:
  serviceName: testsfs-srv
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testsfs
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testsfs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-c
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-vol
          mountPath: /www
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: nginx-vol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: mypv
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

pvc создаётся но не видит pv, хотя указываю "storageClassName: mypv"  в объявлении volumeClaimTemplates

```
    kubectl describe  pvc/nginx-vol-testsfs-0
Name:          nginx-vol-testsfs-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  mypv
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=testsfs
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                From                             Message
  ----     ------              ----               ----                             -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  4m (x843 over 3h)  persistentvolume-    controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "mypv" not found
```

ns одинаковый,версия v1.10.0 .. буду рад помощи )

Comment: в целом это делается через claimRef или линки

Answer (score 0):

точное указание namespaces, sc , имени, размера и прав доступа помогли. а так же можно указать в pv точное pvc, но опять же важно совподение всех указанных параметров